# Can I attach two secondary monitors to a dedicated PhysX card?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, physx

I'm planning on building a computer using a dedicated NVidia card for PhysX acceleration.

I will have a big central monitor connected to the main graphic card and two side monitors I **will not** use for gaming, but only for desktop applications.

What I'd like to know is if there's a way to connect both monitors to the PhysX card outputs. I know you can do it with one monitor while still using the PhysX acceleration, but is it possible to connect both monitors and use them to display the desktop while the card is still accelerating PhysX at the same time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up building my system using 3 x Radeon 7970 and one GTX650 as a PhysX card.

I can confirm the two side monitors connected to the GTX650 work properly even when the card is being used for PhysX (tested with Borderlands 2).

Comment: Rare are the moments when you have a really specific question to ask and there is actually an answer available :-) (Let's hope this is not only for 650 but also holds for later cards)

Answer (score 0):

If your card has the ports to do so then you should be able to without problem, I've done similar thing with a ATI card before and it worked fine.

Comment: I'm sorry, but you can only use an Nvidia card for PhysX acceleration and I'm not sure it works the same way as a standard video card when used for PhysX. I fear one of the two heads of the card might be used for PhysX only thus shutting down one of the two outputs.
I'd like to have some proofs of it working, if possible.